# I need to figure out the logical bug in my Code

Tags: java

when I call the method "getUnknownsAccel" with the problem1 object, for some reason the 'if' statement in the method is not executed to retrieve the value of the variable:

```
PhysicsProblem problem1 = new PhysicsProblem(accel, vI, vF, t, deltaX);

    System.out.println("Which variable are you solving for? ");
    String solveFor = scan.next();


    // after receiving solveFor input, assesses data accordingly

    if (solveFor.equalsIgnoreCase("acceleration"))
    {
        System.out.println("Solving for Acceleration!");
        System.out.println("Are there any other unknowns? (enter 'none' or the name " +
                "of the variable)");
        missingVar = scan.next();
        problem1.setMissingVar(missingVar);
        do
        {
            problem1.getUnknownsAccel();
            System.out.println("Are there any other unknowns? (enter 'none' or the name " +
                    "of the variable)");
            missingVar = scan.next();               //// change all these in the program to scan.next, not scan.nextLine
        }
        while (!missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("none") || !missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("acceleration"));

        if (missingVar.equals("none"))
        {
            // Write code for finding solutions
            System.out.println("Assuming you have given correct values, the solution is: ");
        }
    }
```

After the do/while loop used to retrieve the name of the other variables that are unknown, I call the getUnknownsAccel method from this class file:

```
public void getUnknownsAccel()
{
    //-----------
    // checks for another unknown value that is not accel
    //-----------
    if (missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("time"))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the value for time: ");
        t = scan.nextDouble();
        while (t <= 0 || !scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("That is not an acceptable value!");
            t = scan.nextDouble();
        }
    }       

}
```

Let's assume for the sake of this problem, that the user WILL enter "time" as the unknown when prompted. Any idea why my code isn't executing the scan function to retrieve the time variable value? Instead, the program just repeats the system.out function "Are there any other unknowns..."

Comment: What is the exact value of `missingVar` when you enter `getUnknownsAccel()`? If you don't have a debugger handy, then you should fix that, but in the meantime, just print it back out before the `if()`.

Comment: assume the person would enter "time" when prompted. I'm assuming missingVar would be equal to "time" when I call getUnknownsAccel(); am I wrong?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I didn't ask what you *assume* is the content of the variable when you call the function; I asked what *actually is* the content of the variable *once inside* the function. Big difference. You seem to have a handful of fairly basic questions on your profile; there's nothing wrong with being a beginner (we were all there once) but in this case it's pretty easy to tell what is actually going wrong. Use a debugger to set a breakpoint, or simply print the value of the variable, allowing you to examine it before the comparison. I'm willing to bet that you will spot the error quickly.

Comment: In this particular case, my first guess would be an errant newline character messing up your comparison, but the debugger will tell you what the actual state of your program is at the time of the comparison, and then you can compare it to what you expect its state to be. The difference between the two will be your problem. The simplest way to find out what is going wrong is applying the scientific method: form a hypothesis, then test it using the development tools that you have at your disposal, make any necessary adjustments to either and repeat until you have solved the problem.

Comment: `while (!missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("none") || !missingVar.equalsIgnoreCase("acceleration"));` condition always true, and thus while loop never exited.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The OP's problem isn't that he isn't exiting from the loop (that'll probably be a next step) but that getUnknownsAccel() doesn't behave as expected when the supposed value of missingVar is `time`.

Comment: It is very, very important to check assumptions when debugging. The more strongly you are assuming something, the more important it is to check. A strongly held assumption can be a blind spot that hides a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scanning, you set missingVar to scan.next(), but you do not do anything.  The loop continues.

After

```
missingVar = scan.next();
```

add the line

```
getUnknownsAccel();
```

Note, another issue is that you will need to handle later is that missingVar is local - to access it in getUnknownsAccel(), you should change the declaration to

```
public void getUnknownsAccel(String missingVar){
}
```

and instead use
    getUnknownsAccel(missingVar);

Comment: We don't know that `missingVar` is a local variable. In fact, it looks to me to be an instance variable on the class, and the declaration of it just isn't included in the question.